# How can I boot directly into an application?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-11.10

How can I disable and hide all menus for a specific user and start only one program?

What I mean is, I would like my user to login and see only the background image and the one program that the script would run.

Comment: What you're looking for is called Kiosk mode, here is an example of a way to do it in ubuntu: http://ze.phyr.us/kiosk-mode-in-linux